# How to return value from async function that returns promise fullfiled, typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I have a problem with returning an actual value from the async function in ts(JSX). My functions return Promises, but I need actual value can you help me? And also my getNFTAttributes fun returns an error that it can't read the value of undefined('data'), but it works normally?

```
  const getAllNftData = async () => {

  const connect = createConnectionConfig(clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta"));
  const provider = getProvider();
  let ownerToken = provider.publicKey;

  const nfts = await getParsedNftAccountsByOwner({
    publicAddress: ownerToken,
    connection: connect,
    //serialization: true,
  });

  

  return nfts;
};

// Funkcija koja filtrira(odabire) NFT TAP konfiguracije 
const filterNFTs = async () => {
  
  const nfts = await getAllNftData();
  let result = nfts.filter(obj => {
    if (obj.updateAuthority === "GfFvjKW7apgpxqHLw2bLmRbk1fVBqiESNq2kRffFwXTi") {
      return obj;
    }
  })

  return result;
}

const  getNFTAttributes = async () => {

  const nft = await filterNFTs();

  const getJSON = async (uri) => {
    const response = await fetch(uri);
    return response.json(); // get JSON from the response 
  };

  console.log("JSON fetching......");
  let jsonNFTData = await getJSON(nft[0].data.uri);

  return jsonNFTData.attributes;
}

//funkcije sve posebno za name , surname i OIB

const getNameOfPerson = async () => {

  const attributes = await getNFTAttributes();

  let traitType = await attributes[0].trait_type;
  try {
    if (traitType == "Name") {
      var nameOfPerson = await attributes[0].value;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
 
  return nameOfPerson;
}

const getSurnameOfPerson = async () => {

  const attributes = await getNFTAttributes();

  let traitType = await attributes[1].trait_type;
  try {
    if (traitType == "Surname") {
      var surnameOfPerson = await attributes[1].value;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  
  return surnameOfPerson;
}

async function getOibOfPerson() {
  const attributes = await getNFTAttributes();
  let traitType = await attributes[2].trait_type;
  try {
    if (traitType == "OIB") {
      var oibOfPerson = await attributes[2].value;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  
  return oibOfPerson;
}

 //for example
let name = getNameOfPerson();
console.log(name) //Promise {<pending>}
                       //[[Prototype]]: Promise
                       //[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
                       //[[PromiseResult]]: "Ivan"
```

When I add await getNameOfPerson... It says me that I must add await to containing function and when I add it, an error appears to index.tsx where is all linked that App doesn't return proper JSX element. Also, I have a problem with the constant loading of Solana web API which I can't fix it and my buttons in the frontend are not working, because of that. I know it's big deal, but I tried to fix this for a couple of days, I have searched the whole Stackoverflow and nothing works for me. Thanks for your help I really appreciate it.

Comment: 1. Don't add `await` to random statements like `var surnameOfPerson = await attributes[1].value;` 2. you cannot call async functions inside your JSX. --- In general you load data in a useEffect callback with an empty dependency array. You'll also need `let name = await getNameOfPerson();` because `getNameOfPerson` is async. Without await you'll get the unresolved Promise.

Comment: by definition, any function that is `async function` returns a Promise, regardless if the function has any asynchronous behaviour or not